# I am trying to add spacing between my search logo and the border in my searchBox

Tags: html, css

My search logo is stuck to the left side of my search box which I told it to do but I am trying to get a little spacing in between the two.

```css
#searchBox {
  flex: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-image-outset: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff url(images/search-logo.png)left center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBox">
  <form method="get">
    <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your position to something like `background-position: 10px center;`? (you can pull this into the longhand, of course) You'll need to adjust your `padding-left` too, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet. Just add background-position and increase input padding.

```css
#searchBox {
  flex: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-image-outset: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff url("https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/search.png") 10px 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBox">
  <form method="get">
    <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```